# sed command to replace " with ' only in lines that doesn't match a pattern

Tags: regex, linux, sed

My text looks like this:

'test' file:

```
123,James,123,"
hello "X"
this is a "string", cool.
another "string", here.
",7
```

My goal:
in all lines that doesn't match the pattern `[^number,string,number]` or `[^",number]`
replace
`"` with `'`.

meaning, the out put should like:

```
123,James,123,"
hello 'X'
this is a 'string', cool.
another 'string', here.
",7
```

my sed command so far is:

```
sed '/\(^[0-9]*,.*,[0-9]*\|^",[0-9]\)/!s/"/'/g' test
```

my problem is in the substitue part, i'm trying to escape but it doesn't let me, and i can't seems to find a solution to it. if i try to switch `'` with `#` for example, it works.
I tried : `...!s/"/\'/g'` but it doesn't work.

Would love your help! thanks!

[SOLVED]:
for those who also have this problem, i switched the open paranthese to `"` and escaped also the `!`
the solution:

`sed "/\(^[0-9]*,.*,[0-9]*\|^\",[0-9]\)/\!s/\"/'/g"`

Comment: Why are you not changing `",7` line in your shown output? It is not starting from digits? Kindly elaborate more on same, thank you.

Comment: this is a data set which I need to upload to data base, thus i need to replace all of the " to ' so i i can extract only the text, so i need to keep that line ```",7``` as it is. so i need to change all of the lines that doesn't apply to this pattern is well, but keep these line with ```"``` and not changed them to ```'```

Comment: This looks like malformed CSV data. The proper fix is to double the literal double quotes.

Comment: When you are happy with your own solution, please post it as an answer and accept it. That way other helpers know your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk` should work in any `awk` version.

```bash
awk '!/^"/ && !/^[0-9]+.*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+/{gsub(/"/,"\047")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: I've tried this command, but it also changed the ```"``` to ```'``` on the first line, which i want to leave as it is

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/^(",)?[0-9]+($|,[[:alpha:]]+,[0-9])/!s/"/'"'"'/g' input_file
123,James,123,"
hello 'X'
this is a 'string', cool.
another 'string', here.
",7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed -E` so that you don't have to escape the parenthesis.

Note that:

- if you use `[0-9]*` you will match optional digits, `[0-9]+` matches 1 or more digits.
- For the `string` part you use `.*` but that matches the whole line

For example

```
sed -E "/(^[0-9]+,.*,[0-9]|^\",[0-9])/!s/\"/'/g" test
```

Using `awk` and if for example in the first check there can be only 2 comma's:

```
awk '!/^(",[0-9]|[0-9]+,[^,]*,[0-9])/{gsub(/"/,"\047")}1' test
```

Both will output:

```
123,James,123,"
hello 'X'
this is a 'string', cool.
another 'string', here.
",7
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^("|[0-9]+,[^,]+),[0-9]+/!y/"/'\''/' file
```

If the line does not match the required strings then translate all `"`'s to `'`'s.

N.B. The idiom `'\''` punches a hole into the shell and `\'` then quotes the single quote.